# Where can I buy the complete bands of "Princess" manhwa from 1995?

Tags: resources, princess

So I read this manhwa and it's called *Princess* from 1995. It's old but gold.

I really want to buy the physical bands but I can't find them.

Has anyone heard of this manhwa and knows where I could buy them?
Or does someone generally know where to buy old manga that aren't being printed anymore?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to A&M! Which language are you looking for specifically? If english, it might be a tad tough to find fresh prints, as the english publisher went defunct.